# Having trouble adding a callback function from the main.js to the renderer.js after button click in another window

Tags: javascript, electron

Hi at the moment i have used the ipcRenderer in one of my JS files to execute a function in the main.js. This code executes without a problem. What I'm trying to do straight after is send a callback function to the main **renderer.js** file so that i can execute another function which manipulates the appearance of some icons in the main window.

main.js code:

```
ipcMain.on('ReadyBtn', (event) => { 
console.log('request received')
ToggleReady();
event.returnValue = "toggle ready test";
})
```

sidebar.js code - this file is where I'm using the ipc renderer:

```
const ReadyBtn = document.getElementById('btnReady') 
ReadyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
ipcRenderer.sendSync("ReadyBtn")

});
```

The code above works fine, when the button is clicked the toggleReady() function within the main.js file is triggered.

What i would now like to do is set up a call back function in the **renderer.js** file so that i can execute another function "stateReady()", after the button is clicked. Below is what i have so far:

```
(async () =>{
await ipcRenderer.invoke('ReadyBtn')
stateReady();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Noting that you have not included your `preload.js` script in your question, I have added the below `preload.js` script
which has no concrete implementations in it (apart from the IPC methods), only configuration of whitelisted channel names.

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': [
            'ReadyBtn' // Channel name
        ]
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

This `preload.js` script is used like so.

```js
/**
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    windowName.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await promiseName(data)
 *                  .then(() => { return result; })
 *          });
 */
```

---

In your `main.js` file you will use the [`handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener) method to listen for a message on the `ReadyBtn` channel, process the request and then `return` a response.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.handle('ReadyBtn', (event, message) => {
    console.log('Request received'); // Testing
    // toggleReady();
    return 'Toggle ready test';
})
```

---

In your `index.html` file, you will use the [`invoke`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args) method to `send` a message on the `ReadyBtn` channel to the main process and `then` wait for a response.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Button">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.invoke('ReadyBtn')
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result); // Testing
                    console.log('Request received'); // Testing
                    // stateReady();
                })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```